# How to sum columns containing arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a problem to summarize the columns of a dataframe containing arrays in each cell. 
[image: dataframe]
I tried to summarize the columns using df.sum(), expecting to get the total column array, for example [4,1,1,4,1] for the column 'common'.
But I got only an empty Series.

```py
df_sum = df.sum()
print(df_sum)

Series([], dtype: float64)
```

How can I get the summarized column in this case?

Comment: Isn't your df.sum() argument empty here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, working with `object` `dtypes` in pandas DataFrames are usually not a good idea, especially filling cells with python lists, because you lose performance.

Nevertheless, you may accomplish this by using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
df.apply(lambda s: list(it.chain.from_iterable(s.dropna())))
```

You may also use `sum`, but I'd say it's slower

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.dropna().sum())
```

I can see why you'd think `df.sum` would work here, even setting `skipna=True` explicitly, but the vectorized `df.sum` shows a weird behavior in this situation. But then again, these are the downsides of using a DataFrame with lists in it

Comment: thanks for the response and the performance hint. I'm using actually dataframes for simplicity and to visualize the data. But I know that later I will have to migrate to a more efficient data structure.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can probably just use list comprehension to handle your task:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d1':[np.nan, [1,2], [4]], 'd2':[[3], np.nan, np.nan]})

>>> df
       d1   d2
0     NaN  [3]
1  [1, 2]  NaN
2     [4]  NaN

df_sum = [i for a in df['d1'] if type(a) is list for i in a]

>>> df_sum
[1, 2, 4]
```

If you need to do sum on the whole DataFrame (or multiple columns), then use [numpy.ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten the dataframe before using the list comprehension.

```
df_sum = [i for a in np.ravel(df.values) if type(a) is list for i in a]

>>> df_sum
[3, 1, 2, 4]
```